# How to create an AJAX request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create an AJAX request using jQuery 'after' a user has finished entering an 11 digit mobile number into a form field? 'kinda like a user name available check'

case...

User to enters a mobile number into form field

AJAX request made, mobile number sent http://domain.com?mobile=xxx

If result retuned is 'true' change box to green else red

Example

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: 'get',
                            url: 'http://domain.com',
                            data: {
                                apiKey: ''
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            context: document.body,
                            success: function(r) {
                                console.log(r);
                            }
                        });

                });
            </script>
```

Comment: *[what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)*

Comment: Is the URL you're calling from AJAX on your own domain?

Comment: No not on my domain an external one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var digits = /^\d{11}$/;

$("input").on("keyup", function() {
    if ( digits.test(this.value) ) {
        $.ajax({
            url    : "/foo/bar",
            data   : { id: 1337 },
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for adding a preliminary check before invoking the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `on()` method to attach to the key/paste event(s) of the input field, and follow that with a call to `$.ajax()`, passing the appropriate parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo/',
     data: { name: "text to validate" },
     success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
     }
 });
```

On: http://api.jquery.com/on/
AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/